# I need to insert data from docx file into my sqlite db

Tags: python, django, docx

I need to import data (text) from docx file into my sqlite db.

i have this code in my models.py, but  does not work.
Any idea

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import docx2txt
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_read = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(User.get_email_field_name(),default='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_post(self):
    txt = docx2txt.process("/home/master/Downloads/test1.docx")
    post = Post
    post.title = txt.readline()
    post.author = "master"
    post.category = txt.readline()
    post.content = txt.readlines()
    post.save()
```

Comment: Error msg would be useful

Answer (score 0):

post = Post .... shouldn't it be post = Post() ... ???

or

```
post =Post(title = txt.readline(), author = "master", category = txt.readline(), content = txt.readlines())
post.save()
```

Hard to tell without error message.

Comment: Thank you,I have no error at all, or i don't know how to debug... My server run normally, i have my page running, but there is no new post  from file.

Comment: post =Post(title = txt.readline(), author = "master", category = txt.readline(), content = txt.readlines())
post.save() ------------and try it like that

Answer (score 0):

ok i managed:
it's:

```
def get_post(self):
txt = docx2txt.process("/home/master/Downloads/test1.docx")
post = Post.objects.create()
post.title = txt.readline()
post.author = "master"
post.category = txt.readline()
post.content = txt.readlines()
post.save()
```

thank you Jay and Adam